# Intent between activities is not working

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I am using intents to pass objects from an activity to another activity.

In this case, I am passing values to be used as map markers on the second activity.

From the source activity, I am using the following method to open the second activitiy:

```
public void openMapa(View view){

         //Starting single contact activity
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                Empresas_Mapa.class);
        Log.v("LATITUD EN EMPRESAS SIMPLE", latitudEmpresa);
        in.putExtra(TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA, nombreEmpresa);
        in.putExtra(TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA, direccionEmpresa);
        in.putExtra(TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA, latitudEmpresa);
        in.putExtra(TAG_LONGITUDEMPRESA, longitudEmpresa);


        startActivity(in);


    }
```

To check that the passing values are right, you may see a log, which shows the expected value for latitudEmpresa.

And this is the code for the second activity:

```
public class Empresas_Mapa extends Activity{

    static final LatLng CANARIAS = new LatLng(27.9405285, -15.5566901);

      private GoogleMap map;

    String nombreEmpresa;
    String direccionEmpresa;
    String latitudEmpresa;
    String longitudEmpresa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapa_activity_main);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        nombreEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA");
        direccionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("TAG_DIRECCIONEMPRESA");
        latitudEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("LATITUDEMPRESA");
        longitudEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("LONGITUDEMPRESA");
        Log.v("LATITUD EN EMPRESAS MAPA", latitudEmpresa);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();



         // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CANARIAS, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //

            Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

            .title(nombreEmpresa)
             .position(new LatLng(
                 Double.parseDouble(latitudEmpresa),
                 Double.parseDouble(longitudEmpresa)

             ))
             .snippet(direccionEmpresa)
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ofertas))
        );
    }


}
```

But the intent is not passing and getting anything.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: nombreEmpresa = i.getStringExtra(TAG_NOMBREEMPRESA); and same in other three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for the wrong value. You are using the `value` to check when you should be checking the `key` (first param in `putExtra()`)

For instance, here you are using the value you want to pass

```
latitudEmpresa = i.getStringExtra(""LATITUDEMPRESA"");
```

but this is wrong. Assuming the `key` you set is `static`, you would check with

```
latitudEmpresa = i.getStringExtra(ActivityOneName.TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA);
```

You aren't using a key named, `"LATITUDEMPRESA"`. You are passing with a `key` of `TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA`. So the `Intent` *is* passing the data but you aren't retrieving it appropriately.

Comment: That means, the way I am pasing the data is OK, the only problem now is the way the second activity is getting the data. And putting, as example for the latitude: latitudEmpresa = i.getStringExtra(Empresas_SingleItemView.TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA); it should work?

Comment: From what I see, yes.

Comment: After changing the code as you propose, there are errors: The field Empresas.SingleItemView.TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA is not visible. ?

Comment: Then you need to change the declaration of it to something like `public static TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA = "Some String";`. The key there is making it `public` so it can be seen by other classes. I'm assuming you have it as `private`.

Comment: On the first activity?

Comment: All are private static final: private static final String TAG_LATITUDEMPRESA = "";

Comment: Yes, I told you that they probably were. Change `private` to `public`. Probably `protected` is better here than `public`.

Comment: [See the Java scope Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2FjavaOO%2Faccesscontrol.html&ei=03lUU_CqDueEygH77YGQDA&usg=AFQjCNG2JbCG5Z9HNjkLy8i8uxfYDiq3Nw&sig2=lYs1xmiWYxpZuUoL0WxD_A&bvm=bv.65058239,d.aWc)

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. Thank you. I will take a look at your proposed Docs.